# ExpressJS pass data to public js file

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, backend

I am new in ExpressJS, I know how to pass data from backend to the an ejs page, but I wanted to know how to pass data to a js file in the public folder?

So to pass data to a js file ( which js file is in the same folder as ejs ) while rendering the ejs page in the same time .

From ExpressJS I pass data to ejs by rendering ejs page like this

```
  exports.user_signup = (req, res, next) => {
     res.render('login', { page:'Login', email: req.body.email, idd: user[0]._id,} );
  }
```

The ejs file :

```
<script src="file1.js"></script>


<%= email %>
```

So what I want, is to pass some data from ExpressJS to file1.js (which is in public folder)..

Answer (score 0):

You cant access ejs data in a Javascript file or pass in data to a js file.
One possible way, Is that you can make use of variable passed to an ejs file.

- Copy in your JS code to your `ejs` file and enclose them in a `<script>` tag.
- pass in your required data to the ejs file ( in our case `index.ejs` ).

```js
res.render('index', {data: 'some data'});
```

- Inside the `<script>` tag in ejs file you can access the data like.

```js
<script>
 var x= <%- data %>;
 console.log(x);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi man, I  know how to pass data in the ejs, but my question was to pass to a js file. Updated my question..